# PhoneGap android page navigation

Tags: android, cordova

I am a newbie to Android development and was using PhoneGap to develop a simple application. Can anyone please answer the below questions?

In all the sample applications found in the internet, they use a single index.html file. How to develop an application in phonegap containing more than one page?

How can we navigate from one page to another?

I want to have the same code to work in iphone also, so if I create more than one activity will the same code work in Iphone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, it was a dumb question and since I was new to phonegap development I had no idea what I was doing.

The problem was that at the beginning I considered it like developing an android application. If you consider it like developing a website, you will find that the answer is very simple.

So for example, in my home page I provided two anchor tags which will point to my webpages which will handle the other two functionalities. ie. In my sample application to create and list profiles, the homepage would look like this.

> < a href="addProfile.html" style="styling for the anchor to look like a button"/>
>
> < a href="listProfile.html" style="styling for the anchor to look like a button"/>

Answer (score 0):

We use JavaScript to navigate between all of the pages we have in our application, navigating within a frame.

And yes, if it works in PhoneGap, it should work in both Android and iOS.